# No configuration setting found for key in scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, intellij-idea, akka

I am working with a scala project and I am getting following error while running it:

```
 No configuration setting found for key 'aws'
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:156)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:149)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:250)
[error]         at one.fxr.ams.common.Settings$.<init>(Settings.scala:15)
[error]         at one.fxr.ams.common.Settings$.<clinit>(Settings.scala)
[error]         at one.fxr.ams.common.SentryLogger.<init>(SentryLogger.scala:9)
[error]         at one.fxr.ams.service.MainServer$.main(MainServer.scala:11)
[error]         at one.fxr.ams.service.MainServer.main(MainServer.scala)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
```

According to what I understand it might be facing issues in reading aws configs in my conf file.
which is defined like:

```
aws{
  dynamodb{
    table.transaction.ehi = "finance-transactions-ehi-message-development"
    table.transaction.ehi =${?DYNAMODB_TABLE_TRANSACTION_EHI}
    table.finance.account.transaction =  "das_finance_account_transactions_dev"
    table.finance.account.transaction = ${?DYNAMODB_TABLE_FINANCE_ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION}
  }
}
```

But the confusing part is the project is running fine with same command in my colleague's system. i.e.

```
sbt -DDB_READER_HOST=localhost:3306  -DDB_WRITER_HOST=localhost:3306  -DDB_USERNAME=sachin -DDB_PASSWORD=mypassword  -DMAIN_SERVER=GRPC  -Dconfig.resource=development.conf run
```

Comment: What is the content of `development.conf`?

Comment: the releavent one is aws one I already mentioned. there are other configs also

Comment: Are you sure you include the `conf` file containing what you attached into `development.conf`?

Comment: yeah @TomerShetah and actually me and my colleague are on same commit so I don't think it might be a code related issue.

Comment: in case you are using Akka, are you getting the config file by `val awsConfig = ConfigFactory.load("development.conf").getConfig("aws")` and then creating you ActorSystem by calling `ActorSystem("AWSSystem", awsConfig)`?

Comment: @Felipe I am using ```  val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.load().resolve().getString("path of configuration") ``` and the same code is running on my colleague's machine

Comment: I think that the default `ConfigFactory.load()` loads the file `application.conf` unless you configured it in other configuration of your project. Maybe is worthwhile to test `ConfigFactory.load("development.conf")` without `.resolve()` because on the doc says: that `resolve()` `Returns a replacement config with all substitutions`

Comment: @Felipe issue got resolved when i used double quotes over development.conf in run command. but the earlier command was working on another system.